# Is there dependency incompatibility for mongoosastic & mongoose to index docs with elasticsearch?

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, mongoose, mongoosastic

I am using mongoosastic 3.1.2, mongoose ~4.0.5, mongodb 3.0.3 and elasticsearch 1.6 where I get the mapping of my collections but existing documents couldn't indexed in elastic search and the problem is also in

```js
function SyncCollection (){
    var stream = model.synchronize()
        , count = 0;

    stream.on('data', function(err, doc){
        count++;
    });
    stream.on('close', function(){
        console.log('indexed ' + count + ' documents from Collection!');
    });
    stream.on('error', function(err){
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Where the stream.on method is not working.

Thanks in advance.